# GridFS identical filename overwrites file using C Driver

Tags: c, mongodb, gridfs

I am new to `mongodb` and read about the `GridFS` for storing Files but when I am storing Files in `GridFS`, I am facing two problems

1) When I am writing a file into `GridFS` using `C Driver`, having the same filename as a file stored earlier, the first file is going to be overwritten. So I am wondering that is it actually true that the same filename can only exist once in the database or am I doing something wrong? If it is true then how can i write both files in the database system?

2) When I am writing back the files from the database to the disk, the file is corrupted. I read on the net that `C Driver` has some bugs related to this issue. So is there anyone who can tell me whether that bug is fixed or not?

Writing to DB:

```
        mongo conn[1];
        int status = mongo_client( conn, mongo_addr, MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT );
        if(status != 0)
        {
           //Error
        }
        gridfs gfs[1];
        gridfs_init( conn, db, collection, gfs );
        gridfs_store_file( gfs, filePath, fileName, fileType, GRIDFILE_DEFAULT );
        gridfs_destroy( gfs );
        mongo_disconnect( conn );
        mongo_destroy( conn );
```

This writing code is working perfectly.

Reading from DB:

```
mongo conn[1];
    int status = mongo_client( conn, mongo_addr, MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT );
// Mongo_client cannot connect to DB
if(status != 0)
{
    //Error
}

gridfs gfs[1];
gridfs_init( conn, db, collection, gfs );
gridfile gfile[1];
FILE *stream;


if(!gridfile_exists( gfile ))
 {
    //Error ("Error: No such file in DB");
}

fp = fopen( filePath, "w+" );
// Error while writing fetched file to disk
if(gridfile_write_file( gfile, fp ) == -1)
   {
        //Error ("Error: Could not write to disk");
    }
fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );
fclose( fp );
```

The file is written to the disk but are corrupted.

Comment: #1) Yes, that would be by design. The second file should have a unqiue name if it is in fact different. #2) What bug are you referring to? You'll need to provide a source.

Comment: WiredPrairie...[this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-126) is the link...they said it fixed but unfortunately i am unable to find the solution.

Comment: What version of the C driver are you using, and on what O/S version? The CDRIVER-126 issue you referenced has a fixVersion of 0.90, but seems to be referring to a bug in a test case on Windows. It doesn't mention corruption so I think it isn't relevant to your problem. Can you include some of your code for writing/reading the file from GridFS? The C driver has recently been significantly refactored so you should make sure you are using the right API. The [examples for the new C driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/examples/) include GridFS.

Comment: My O/S is windows-7 64 bit and i am using c Legacy driver (new name according to mongodb GitHub repository). The link you mentioned in your comment is using new C-Driver but i am using C Legacy Driver in which the latest version was 0.85. I contacted with new C driver authors and they said it doesn't support windows right now but in future they will add the compatibility version for windows also. I am editing my question with the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: The new C driver has full support for windows now (based on cmake, even comes with pre-built binaries).  If you're still blocked, that should be a well supported solution.